# Contact Form: Email Not Sent

Tags: php, contact-form

My contact form does not send an email when the user inputs their contact details and presses the submit button. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="row">
    <form action="mail.php" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
    <div class="form-group contacts-form-result">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <strong></strong>    
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your name *" name="name" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address *" name="email" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <textarea placeholder="Your message *" rows="7" name="message" class="form-control" required></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-2">Send Enquiry</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $mailTo = "myemail@email.com";
  $headers = "Enquiry from: ".$mailFrom;
  $txt = "Name: ".$name."\n"."Message: ".$message;

mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);

 header("Location: success.html?mailsent");

}?>
```

How can I fix this, so that on button press, an email is sent? Thank you.

Comment: Please add filenames to the files you provided so some context is available. Also try adding some logs inside of your PHP code to debug this yourself step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking for a form element named `submit`:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

But you don't have one *named* `submit`.  Just the *type* `submit`.  Give it a name:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-2">Send Enquiry</button>
```

In the key/value pairs sent to the server when posting a form, the element's `name` attribute is the key.  Without a name, it's not sent to the server.